# multi-line label and font size tikztimingtable tikz-timing

Tags: fontsize, tikz-timing

Here is my mwe:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}%to draw
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikztimingtable}[timing/slope=0,timing/coldist=1,timing/rowdist=2,yscale=2,xscale=2,font = \tiny]
{Global Clock} & 16{C}\\
63 & {LHLLLLLLLLLHLLLL}\\
\extracode
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \vertlines[help lines,dashed]{}
    \horlines[help lines]{}
\end{scope}


\end{tikztimingtable}

\end{document}
```

I would like to be able to split Global clock in two lines to make the picture narrower.

I would also like to remove the unnecessary lines on the right side of the signals, which arose after I changed the font size with the command font = \tiny. It must be because that is not the proper way of setting the font size.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `\shortstack{... \\ ...}` to stack words on top of each other. This works basically anywhere as well as in a `tikztimingtable`.

The extra lines seem to come because of the use of `\tiny` which reduces the size of the timing lines as well but is not taken into account for the extra code. In this case I suggest to add the right number of coloumns manually.

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}%to draw
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikztimingtable}[timing/slope=0,timing/coldist=1,timing/rowdist=2,yscale=2,xscale=2,font = \tiny]
{\shortstack{Global\\Clock}} & 16{C}\\
63 & {LHLLLLLLLLLHLLLL}\\
\extracode
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \vertlines[help lines,dashed]{1,...,8}
    \horlines[help lines]{}
\end{scope}

\end{tikztimingtable}

\end{document}
```